# Celery run task only in a given time range

Tags: celery, django-celery

What would be the best way to run Celery tasks only during a specified time range (let's say only at night from 10 pm to 8 am)? No new tasks should be run outside of that time range (it's a must). A possible option I can think of would be to check the time at the beginning of the task and if not in the range raise a `self.retry` with a provided `eta` to re-schedule it at another time.

Is this the best way to do it or are there better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery does not provide that feature out-of-box. I think your plan is a good one (to test whether task is executing at the right time and if not re-schedule itself).